# Update THREE.Mesh.position onchange event with slider

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, slider, onchange

Hi all I'm working on mesh translations using  (Three.js library). I use HTML sliders to update the values so it can be changed with JavaScript.

My Example:

[image: description image]

This works fine but I don't know what is going on with the event listeners of the sliders. Basically what is happening is that the function is in **onchange attribute** but it looks like it works like **onclick**:

```
<input type="range" value=n; min=n; max=n; 
    onchange="set_Radius()";
>
input type="range" value=n; min=n; max=n; 
    onchange="set_Theta()";
>
```

To move the cube i use:

```
animate() {
   var sphericalPos = new THREE.Spherical(get_Radius(), get_Theta(), 0);  
   cube_Mesh.position.setFromSpherical(sphericalPos);
}
```

---

ISSUE: This works only when I release the mouse click from the slider. For example if I move the slider radius from 50 to 150 it would only update 50 & 150 but not any numbers between.

## Q1 : Is there any way that I can achieve the above issue?

## Q2 : Is it possible to lock the face direction of the cube, so that it could stare at the origin at any position (e.g. similar with OrbitController on L_Click Mouse event)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `oninput` event listener instead of `onchange`.
2. Use [`.lookAt()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt) method to face the cube to the origin.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot @prisoner849